# Cloudbuild + lerna: right way to use it

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, yarnpkg, lerna, google-cloud-build

Ok, I was thinking how should be the right way to deploy a project in cloudbuild using lerna, but I don't get it yet.

For example, my intention is to have something like this(pseudo)

```
1. docker image: node:8.12.0
2. install lerna
3. lerna bootstrap
4. lerna run build
5. docker build
6. docker push
```

and this is what I have (not exactly, just example):

```
- name: node:8.12.0
  args: ["yarn", "add", "-W", "lerna@^3.13.3"]
- name: node:8.12.0
  args: ["yarn", "lerna", "bootstrap"]
- name: node:8.12.0
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: ["yarn", "lerna", "run", "build"]
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
......
```

it is the right way to do it??

Answer (score 0):

You are likely better off having your own Dockerfile and building it in cloud build. I know nothing about `lerna` but the traditional dockerfile would be something like this:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM node:8.12.0
WORDKIR /app
ADD package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install
ADD . .
RUN yarn lerna bootstrap \
    && yarn lerna run build
```

then simply call docker build as required

```
# cloudbuild.yaml
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '.']
```